# Setup QABDI (Qlik Associative Big Data Index) on virtual machine

Tags: kubernetes, virtual-machine, kubectl, qliksense

I am trying to setup QABDI on a virtual machine using the following:

(1) kubectl

(2) VirtualBox

(3) Minikube (Sandbox version of Kubernetes)

(4) Windows Server 2012R2

I have succesfully installed (1)-(3) on (4) but when I try to turn on the Minikube (3) using VirtualBox (2) I get an error.

This is the command I am using to start Minikube from PowerShell:

```
minikube start --no-vtx-check
```

And this is the error message I get:

```
vBoxManage.exe: error: The native API dll was not found (C:Windows\system32\WinHvPlatform.dll) (VERR_NEM_NOT_AVAILABLE)

vBoxManage.exe: error: VT-x is not available (VERR_VMX_NO_VMX)
vBoxManage.exe: error: Details: code E_FAIL (0x80004005), component ConsoleWrap, interface IConsole

Details: ... Power up failed (vrc=VERR_VMX_NO_VMX, rc=E_FAIL (0x80004005)
```

I am suspecting that the reason why it is not working is because Minikube doesn't support nested virtual machines.

I am not sure how to move on from here.

Has anyone encountered this error?

Comment: I will change my assumption to: It is because my machine is Server 2012R2 VM in Azure. Nested virtualization is supported in 2016,  not in 2012.

Answer (score 0):

Minikube will not initialize because nested virtualization is not supported in Windows Server 2012R2 in Azure.